# improve / better way to serve pre-compiled asset secure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, assets

For reasons im serving a specific .SWF file outside my /assets folder.
The idea is like this:

```
def get_swf
    send_file("#{Rails.root}/app/assets_protected/game.swf", :disposition => "inline")
end
```

This allows me to do certain checks ( user logged-in,etc) in this method and not have this .SWF be part of my /assets folder.

I load this method with swfobject.js inside my page but a direct call to this URL would just serve up the .SWF file as download.

- Does anyone have suggestions to prevent the download of the file when called url directly?
- Is there any better way to handle this ?

Im not that happy that the file gets downloaded and perhaps this can be worked around.

Comment: if your browser can download that asset using JS, then curl can do it too. I dont think its possible to distinguish if call is coming from JS or curl...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are two issues here. The first is the question of whether you can prevent something from being downloaded directly, but still load it into the browser.

This is simply not possible. If they are going to view the .swf, it is already on their computer. It is a part of the browser's cache, so you simply cannot simultaneously give it to users and prevent them from getting it directly.

The second issue is protecting this file. I see a couple of options here.

- Allow only certain trusted users access to the file. (Sounds like you may be doing something like this already)
- Let people have normal access to your .swf, but pull out the confidential functionality that you are worried about, and put it in a server side web-service call. For example, if you have some actionscript that calculates the user's score based on some variables, you would remove that function, put it in a server-side webservice, and call that from your actionscript (I assume this is possible, but I am not a Flash developer.)
- This is only a mitigation, but there are tools for obfuscating swf files. This may be enough for you to feel confident allowing your SWF to go into the wild. Understand that this is not bulletproof, and can be reverse-engineered. [Example SWF obsfucator](http://www.amayeta.com/software/swfencrypt/).

Answer (score 2):

You should probably try using `send_data` instead of `send_file` to exploit the data (video) streaming capability of rails.

You may find some hints in this discussion thread [streaming-video-from-a-non-public-directoryrails-3](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/26560/streaming-video-from-a-non-public-directoryrails-3/)